# Why JSON response is not getting parsed?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am making an API call with URLSession and I am getting the error like: **The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format** I don't know why it is happeing.
Even I am able to print the response in string format but not getting parsed.

```
API calling method

func getDashboardCountReq() {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
    
    let userDetails = UserInfo.shared.getCurrentUserDetails()
    
    if let authToken = userDetails?.authToken {
        let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + authToken]
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    }
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in
        do {
            
            if let data = data {
                let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
                print("responseString \(responseString)")
                
                do {
                    let f = try JSONDecoder().decode([DashboardResponseData].self, from: data)
                    print(f.count)
                    
                } catch {
                    print("1232 \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                
                
            } else {
                print("LoginViewModel-> no data found")
            }
        } catch(let error) {
            print("Error A123 \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }.resume()
    
}
```

// Model

```
struct DashboardResponseData: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var approvedrc: String
    var pendingpo: String?
    var assets: String?
    var approvedprs: String?
    var pendingrc: String?
    var approvedpo: String?
    var pendingprs: String?
    var tickets: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case approvedrc = "approvedrc"
        case pendingpo  = "pendingpo"
        case approvedprs = "approvedprs"
        case pendingrc    = "pendingrc"
        case approvedpo = "approvedpo"
        case pendingprs = "pendingprs"
        case tickets = "tickets"
    }
}
```

String Response

```
[{\"approvedrc\":41,\"pendingpo\":566,\"assets\":37956,\"approvedprs\":1040,\"pendingrc\":8,\"approvedpo\":1650,\"pendingprs\":1709,\"tickets\":137872}]
```

// Log

[image]

Comment: You should print `error` instead in your catch to get a more informative error message, `print("Error A123 \(error))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned your data are `Int`, and you are also missing the `assets` in CodingKeys. Try something like this:

```
struct DashboardResponseData: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let approvedrc, pendingpo, assets, approvedprs: Int?
    let pendingrc, approvedpo, pendingprs, tickets: Int?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case approvedrc,pendingpo,assets,approvedprs,pendingrc,approvedpo,pendingprs,tickets
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you much @workingdog support Ukraine

Answer (score 1):

All the values in `DashboardResponseData` are declared as strings, but are integers in the JSON, so you should either parse them as `Int`, or add quotes around them in the JSON.

There it works :

```swift
import Foundation

let json = "[{\"approvedrc\":41,\"pendingpo\":566,\"assets\":37956,\"approvedprs\":1040,\"pendingrc\":8,\"approvedpo\":1650,\"pendingprs\":1709,\"tickets\":137872}]"

struct DashboardResponseData: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var approvedrc: Int
    var pendingpo: Int?
    var assets: Int?
    var approvedprs: Int?
    var pendingrc: Int?
    var approvedpo: Int?
    var pendingprs: Int?
    var tickets: Int?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case approvedrc = "approvedrc"
        case pendingpo  = "pendingpo"
        case approvedprs = "approvedprs"
        case pendingrc    = "pendingrc"
        case approvedpo = "approvedpo"
        case pendingprs = "pendingprs"
        case tickets = "tickets"
    }
}


let f = try JSONDecoder().decode([DashboardResponseData].self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
print(f.count)
```

Also, note that you can simplify this :

```swift
let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
```

which is completely redundant (`String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))` can simply be `String.Encoding.utf8`) to this :

```swift
let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

because enum type `String.Encoding` is deducted as it is the expected type of this argument.